# Are there "rules" (or consistent conventions) that limit when the NY Times Crossword can deviate from rotational symmetry?

Tags: puzzle-creation, crosswords

Most American crosswords use rotational (or "radial") symmetry so that squares directly opposite each other (through the center) are identical.

In the Times, I've only seen this **not** be the case when the layout was directly linked to the theme.  Is that one of the "rules" you can count on, or are there (modern, Will Shortz era) examples of cases where you can't assume that non-radial symmetry will be somehow related to the theme?

Here's an example where the theme **does** justify the deviation:

[image]

The theme in this example was celebrating the 50th anniversary of Frank Lloyd Wright's landmark Guggenheim building.

Comment: Do you mean to ask whether asymmetric crossword puzzles exist that don't follow a specific theme?

Comment: @Emracool, I'm asking whether the modern times puzzle ever deviates from "normal" crossword symmetry without the deviation being linked to the theme - I added an example above of the type I've seen that *is* theme-related.

Comment: It might be a separate question, but are there rules about when the NYT crossword can put multiple letters in one box?

Comment: In an old Games magazine, there was a full page crossword with the title "Breaking the Rules".  The theme clues were all "What this puzzle has and shouldn't" with answers like unchecked letter, asymmetric diagram, two letter words, disconnected section, etc.

Comment: Isn't this really a question for the editor? I'd imagine that there are well defined editorial standards that all submissions to the NYT are expected to follow, and that breaking *any* of those rules would require justification. A clever elaboration of the theme as in the above grid is certainly a good justification for symmetry breaking, but ultimately it was an editor's choice to allow the rule to be broken and I doubt that there is a clear meta-rule that can be stated about that.

Comment: @rberteig,  crosswords, and the times one in particularly, have highly consistent patterns the solver can rely on  (all boxes are "crossed", abbreviations must be indicated in the clue, question marks indicate puns or non-standard readings, etc.)  The question is essentially whether it appears safe to assume that the layout will always be a certain way except in cases where the theme relates to the non-standard layout.

Comment: @Jaydles, of course. But since the convention is that the published puzzles follow the rules, I doubt that anyone other than the puzzle editor can answer a question about when it would be acceptable to break them. The best we could do is collect some examples. The submission guidelines for the NYT daily puzzle were pretty strict when I last read them in the 90s, and most other editors followed suit.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Nearly all the Times crossword grids have rotational symmetry: they
>   can be rotated 180 degrees and remain identical. Rarely, puzzles with
>   only vertical or horizontal symmetry can be found; yet rarer are
>   asymmetrical puzzles, usually when an unusual theme requires breaking
>   the symmetry rule. **This rule has been part of the puzzle since the
>   beginning; when asked why, initial editor Margaret Farrar is said to
>   have responded, "Because it is prettier.**"

***SOURCE:*** ["The Ins and Outs of Across and Down" The New York Times Magazine, 1992-02-16.](http://www.nytimes.com/1992/02/16/magazine/crosswords-fiftyyears.html?ei=5070&en=eb226eeaee1ab061&ex=1237089600&pagewanted=all)

Answer (score 8):

Quality crossword puzzles have had a [rotational symmetry requirement](http://www.cruciverb.com/index.php?action=ezportal;sa=page;p=21) for a very long time. It was determined early on in the development of the puzzle that the symmetry rule (along with the fully checked and all-over interlock rules) made the puzzles more interesting. (IMHO, that is because it puts interesting constraints on the beginnings of words towards the upper left corner, with mirrors of those constraints on the endings of words in the lower right.)

The NYT does expressly give the editor freedom to break the rules, ["if the theme warrants"](http://www.cruciverb.com/index.php?action=ezportal;sa=page;p=16). But notably none of my searches for submissions guidelines to the NYT made any more explicit statements than that.