# On this historic day

Tags: cipher, enigmatic-puzzle, history

Today is 04 17 *2* 017 as of posting this puzzle in my current time.

**What happened on the date I am thinking of?**

> YQTNFYCTKK

1. FOGLQENMILAGTSLJA - 1st
2. BCIXDHEELQJUFQWDENIZ - 8th
3. LSRCODAIJWNPFXEAD - 5th
4. OCLEKARENZWBTPEACFUMOJZNKU - 7th
5. YNVNKKSCWDWYZLFADVAAQRVEHJLRVL - 3rd
6. WZCTHOFIMMLOITV - 1st
7. CSIXDJYZVDWRVDSKLRVL - 5th
8. IIJDRHIEQNWZCD - 7th

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, all the work work was already done by [Sconibulus](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/51090/30887) and [kayzeroshort](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/51095/30887) so, go and up vote their answers.

The answer is -

> On May 14 2014(05-14-2014) Puzzling Stack Exchange was established according to its [first post](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1/are-there-rules-or-consistent-conventions-that-limit-when-the-ny-times-cross) and [first meta post](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/name-the-chat-room)

Answer (score 6):

Top word is

> Rot-2 WorldWarII

Decoding the rest...

> Vigenere: WorldWarII as key
> 1: JapanInvadesChina
> 2: FormalEndingOfTheWar
> 3: PearlHarborBombed
> 4: SouthernFranceBecomesVichy
> 5: CzechoslovakiaCedesSudetenland
> 6: AlliesFreeParis
> 7: GermanyInvadesPoland
> 8: MussoliniFalls

We probably need to do something with the numbers on the right...

> grabbing the nth letter of the decoded phrases, and decoding again yields NZugBear, which seems almost plausible, but I don't think it's right.

Answer (score 6):

Continuing from Sconibulus' cipher...

I think the numbers correspond to

> the nth digit in the MMDDYYYY date of the listed events:
> JapanInvadesChina - (1) - **0**7071937
> FormalEndingOfTheWar - (8) - 0902194**5**
> PearlHarborBombed - (5) - 1207**1**941
> SouthernFranceBecomesVichy - (7) - 071019**4**0
> CzechoslovakiaCedesSudetenland - (3) - 04**2**41938
> AlliesFreeParis - (1) - **0**8251944
> GermanyInvadesPoland - (5) - 0901**1**939
> MussoliniFalls - (7) - 072519**4**3

This gives

> 05142014

What happened on this date?

> A lot of stuff, but nothing that jumps out as the right answer.
>  en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portal:Current_events/2014_May_14 
>  The only connection to WWII is the 56th anniversary of the founding of the state of Israel.

Comment: You're right there, good work on the dates, but the one I am looking for is specific - and not related to WWII